# Cannot subtract from DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have database where I have `TimeStart` and `TimeEnd`, so I want to get only `StudentName` values that they are thirty days to finish. So each `StudentName` has a `TimeStart` and a `TimeEnd`

ViewModel:

```
    public String StudentName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DurationDays { set; get; }
    public int SelectedDurationDays { set; get; }
```

Model:

```
[Key]
public int MyModelId { get; set; }
public String StudentName { get; set; }
public DateTime TimeStart{ get; set; }
public DateTime TimeEnd{ get; set; }
```

So as you can see, I do a `SelectList` item to create a new `TimeStart` and `TimeEnd`, here is my logic:

Create Get:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var vm = new StudentViewModel
        {
            DurationDays = new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "1 year"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "2 years"},
            }};
   return View(vm);
}
```

Create Post

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "TimeStart,TimeEnd,StudentName,SelectedDurationDays")] StudentsViewModel model)
{
    var endDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(model.SelectedDurationDays);
    var students = new Students

    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            StudentName = model.StudentName,
            TimeStart = DateTime.Now,
            TimeEnd = endDate
        };

        db.WebPagesList.Add(students);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //exception Return
    }
}
```

Index GET:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(WebPages model)
{
        var datesub = model.DomainExp.AddDays(-30);

        var datetimened = db.StudentList.Where(x => x.StudentName== model.StudentNAme
               && x.TimeEnd<= datesub);
        var StudentList = db.StudentList.Include(w => w.Student);
        return View(await StudentList.ToListAsync());
}
```

So my attempt to check the values ​​that are about to end is:

```
var datesub = model.TimeEnd.AddDays(-30);
var datetimened = db.MyModelList.Where(x => x.StudentName ==    model.StudentName && x.TimeEnd<= datesub);
```

But I get an error:

> The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.

on this line:

```
var datesub = model.TimeEnd.AddDays(-30);
```

What I'm doing wrong with my query? I only want to select `StudentName` that is near to `TimeEnd`

***EDIT***

As comment of @Stephen Muecke, I need to set `TimeEnd` in GET method, how can I do that if I don't have `TimeEnd` before post (I create it when I post a new Student)?

Comment: What is the value of `TimeEnd` when your calling that query?

Comment: `TimeEnd` is assigned depending of duration days selected, for example, if I select "1 year" in my create view my "TimeEnd"  is `DateTime.Now` + `DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)`, I try to get StudentName that  `TimeEnd` is nearly 30 days in Index List View

Comment: I suggest you debug your code and check the actual value - its almost certainly `1/1/0001` as Darin Dimitrov has indicated

Comment: I go to my ServerExplorer and `TimeEnd` is `03/03/2017 12:00:00 a. m.`

Comment: If the date were that value it would not throw that error (it returns `1/2/2017` - have just tested to be sure). You need to debug your code.

Comment: And no where in your code have you shown how you are setting the value of `model.TimeEnd` - show how you are accessing the database and setting it. All you currently have is a GET method that initializes a new instance of `StudentsViewModel` which will have a default `TimeEnd` of `1/1/0001`

Comment: I update my POST method

Comment: Your edit shows how you save it in the POST method, but you still have not shown how you set the value of `TimeEnd` in the GET method (that's were you said the error is occurring).  The value of `TimeEnd` is `1/1/0001` which will be obvious when you debug your code!

Comment: How can I set my `TimeEnd` value before post in my GET controller? because in POST I select `TimeStart` and with this one I set `TimeEnd`

Comment: You need to edit your question and show the complete code in the GET method so we can understand what your doing.

Comment: khlr has already given you the correct answer. But I guess you have not bothered to even try it. - that will return all students where the `EndTime` is either in the past of within the next 30 days. But your edit refers to a property named `DomainExp` which does not seem to exist (and if it does, it will be `1/1/0001`) so who knows what your really trying to do.

Comment: Ya, I think it and I had not understood his point!

Comment: Why I get this on my output:`SELECT [Extent1].[StudentID] AS [StudentID], [Extent1].[StudentName] AS [StudentName], [Extent1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Extent1].[TimeEnd] AS [TimeEnd].FROM [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent1] WHERE (([Extent1].[StudentName] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[StudentName] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ([Extent1].[TimeEnd] <= @p__linq__1)`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. And since `model.StudentName` is `null`, then I suspect that not what you want either, and the query should be just `var datetimened = db.MyModelList.Where(x => x.TimeEnd <= datesub);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Darin Dimitrov` already mentioned, you're subtracting at an invalid point.

Instead you should *add* 30 days to *today's* date as you want to query those records which would have been expired within this time span.

```
var datediff = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
var studentsAboutToExpire = db.MyModelList
   .Where(x => x.StudentName == model.StudentName && x.TimeEnd<= datediff);
```

Comment: YOU ARE TOTALLY RIGHT!

Answer (score 2):

If `model.TimeEnd` is the default uninitialized [`DateTime.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) (`1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`) then trying to subtract 30 days from it wouldn't work. Make sure that this property has been populated with a real date time before trying to subtract from it.

I suppose that this value was simply not populated when you submitted the value back to your Post action.

Comment: `TimeEnd` is assigned depending of duration days selected, for example, if I select "1 year" in my create view my "TimeEnd"  is `DateTime.Now` + `DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)`

Comment: OK, now make sure that this value actually reaches your Post action and that you have properly assigned a real DateTime to the `model.TimeEnd` property before calling `.Add(-30)` on it.

Comment: I go to my ServerExplorer and `TimeEnd` is `03/03/2017 12:00:00 a. m.` after my post, my query is on Index  not `POST` action, I only want to get this value, substract 30 days and get `StudentName` that aproach to `03/03/2017 12:00:00 a. m.` -30 days

Comment: So you are saying that `model.TimeEnd` is `03/03/2017 12:00:00 a. m.` **just before** calling `.AddDays(-30)` on it?

Comment: No, I create a new Student with `StartDate` and `EndDate`, after I create it, It haves now that values, and I want to get EndDate Value